# How to get vue custom element to connect to another projects components

Tags: apache

I am trying to get one project (shop) to power different urls

```
shop.test  
shop.example.test 
example.test/shop
```

example.test/shop has problem with custom vue elements because it is trying to find  component in example.test instead of in the shop project. I get this error.

```
    Unknown custom element: <buy-details> - did you register the component correctly?  For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

How can I reconfigure this so it looks for components in shop project where they exist.  This is my apache configuration.

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/shop/public"
    ServerName shop.frontendflex.test
    </VirtualHost>


    <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/shop/public"
    ServerName shop.test
    </VirtualHost>
    
    
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/frontendflex/public"
    ServerName frontendflex.test
    Alias "/shop" "C:/xampp/htdocs/shop/public"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/shop/public">
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending many days trying to work this out I stumbled on why this was not working. example.test/shop was looking for app.js in its own project directory instead of the shop one. Changed it to shop/app.js. problem solved.